# Получение исходника из exe-шника

Tags: linux, .net, ubuntu, exe, поиск-программ

Есть для windows хорошая программа - Reflector. Она достает из exe-шника код программы. Есть ли аналог такой программы на linux? что-то  не нахожу

Comment: Задача из ассемблера получить код это как путешествие в прошлое. Представьте себе код **NOP**. С ремаркой : вся программа это полная чушь.

Comment: Вы про .NET Reflector? На английском StackOverflow [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228086/2553424), что MonoDevelop умеет декомпилировать IL EXE и DLL из коробки.

Comment: Не все программы написаны с использованием dotnet

Comment: @MBo, вопрошающий упомянул специфичную программу, так что понятно, что речь идёт только об IL EXE (т. е. EXE с .NET-байткодом внутри).

Comment: @AlexGlebe, ^^^

Comment: Для получения декомпилированного кода в MonoDevelop необходимо добавить интересующий файл как *reference* и дважды щёлкнуть на появившийся пункт. Если среда при добавлении принимает только DLL, можно временно переименовать ваш `.exe` в `.dll` — структурно это одно и то же.

Comment: @Arhad А можно подробнее? я такого никогда не делал

Comment: Насколько я знаю, Reflector сам тоже написан на .net. В чем проблема запустить его на линуксе?